# React native failing to link react-navigation and native-base - (Expo - CRNA Project)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, native-base

In Expo React Native application, Following error occurred when executing `react-native link` after executing `yarn add react-navigation native-base`.

Warning displayed when adding React Navigation and Native-Base

---

```
warning “expo > react-native-maps@0.21.0” has incorrect peer dependency “react-native@^0.51 || ^0.52 || ^0.53 || ^0.54”.
warning “expo > react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.3” has incorrect peer dependency “react@16.0.0-alpha.6”.
warning “expo > react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.3” has incorrect peer dependency “react-native@^0.44.1”.
warning " > react-native@0.55.4" has incorrect peer dependency “react@16.3.1”.
warning “react-native > eslint-plugin-react-native@3.2.1” has unmet peer dependency “eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4.0.0”.
warning “react-navigation > create-react-context@0.2.2” has unmet peer dependency “prop-types@^15.0.0”.
```

---

Error facing while executing react-native link

---

```
PS C:\Projects\proj> react-native link
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Projects\proj\node_modules (81ms)
rnpm-install info Linking assets to ios project
rnpm-install ERR! Something went wrong while linking. Error: Cannot read property ‘pbxprojPath’ of null
Please file an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues
```

---

Comment: I dont find native-base in this log

Comment: This is resolved Supriya. we need not do react-native link as i initiated app from expo. 
for your question, i copied only warning logs which did not have about native base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`react-native link` command is for react-native projects that are created with `react-native init` command to link native dependencies. You can read more about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html).

If your project created with `create-react-native-app` or using expo, please follow [this](https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html) *(Setup with CRNA part)* install process to add Native Base to your project. `react-navigation` is pure JS library that doesn't need any native linking.

> Create React Native project using the CRNA CLI.
>
> CRNA helps you make React Native apps with no build configuration.
>   CRNA works on macOS, Windows, and Linux.
>
> ```
> yarn add native-base --save
> npm install @expo/vector-icons --save
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much. That helps improve my understanding. Thanks. :)

Comment: @ShivaPrakashPokala no problem. Glad that I can help